# Show many radio buttons

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I have 7 radio buttons under one radio group. I rendered them horizontally using `orientation = "horizontal"`. But only 4 can be visible at a time, rest are not.

Is there any way that I could show rest of them in second row while keeping all these 'Radiobuttons' in one 'RadioGroup`?

In case you need my code -

```
    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1.5 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2.5 BHK" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2.5 BHK" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep them all in one RadioGroup (within the layout file)? You can easily implement a radio group in source, i.e., keep a list of all RadioButtons of the group and set listeners which disable all other RadioButtons in the group when one button is checked.

Comment: Well that sounds like a solution, but not a clean one. I thought there has to be some solution to cater my need.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554629/show-many-radio-buttons/44231154#44231154

Comment: @Hasina you have marked this question duplicate with this same question's link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place `RadioButtons` at different places on the screen while keeping them in the same `RadioGroup`. You can't keep them in different rows either (like you want to achieve). Yes, I hate it too.

You can make checkboxes intead, place them the way you want, and then use `setOnCheckedChangedListener` on each of them. So if one of them is checked, call `setChecked(false)` on the others.

Use custom drawable so that they look like radio buttons and not checkboxes.

Comment: Don't want to keep them in at different places, they are not fitting in a row, so wanted to keep them in second row, more like 'text reflow' thing.

Comment: I understand that. Your case is a sub-case of what I said above. Having two different orientations in the same radio group is the same as placing them at different locations.

Comment: i also try this but u can easily shown on screen without any RadioGroup, just simply drag the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollview inside a radio group like this

```
                 <RadioGroup
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">
                <HorizontalScrollView
                   android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1 BHK" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1.5 BHK" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2 BHK" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2.5 BHK" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2 BHK" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2.5 BHK" />
                     </ScrollView>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: It will make it scrollable, but still views will not be visible to user, so will  not be a intuitive design.

Comment: I think you can also use gridview instead of scrollview

Comment: Well @Darpan this also might not be a good approach, as android devices screen sizes vary from 3.5" to 45" so i will strongly discourage usage of radiobuttons horizontally, you never know will 4 options always fit in horizontally..  You must use vertical radio group. HIGHLY RECOMMENDED

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there is not enough place for all of them. Try to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to all RadioButtons. But it can be not very beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width for all Radiobutton

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
```

And also add `android:layout_weight="1"` for every Radio Button.

ex

```
 <RadioButton
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 BHK" 
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace below code from your  xml code**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1.5 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2.5 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2 BHK" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2.5 BHK" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

i also try this within `RadioGroup` and you can select only one at a time it works nice :
[image]

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: This way you can select all the radio buttons at once! This is not what radio buttons are meant for. Google `RadioGroup` and what it does.

Comment: i also try whithin RadioGroup  and u can select only one at a time

Answer (score -1):

My solution to this is to add a LinearLayout inside your RadioGroup layout.
I changed the orientation of the RadioGroup to vertical and added
two LinearLayout with horizontal orientation which will server as rows.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"        
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 BHK" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1.5 BHK" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2 BHK" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2.5 BHK" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3 BHK" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3.5 BHK" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: This way you can select all the radio buttons at once! This is not what radio buttons are meant for.